# Visual Studio C# and SQL Server : connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to connect to a local database (service-based database created in Visual Studio 2013).

I use this C# code:

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"|DataDirectory|\\InvDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";

public int testpripojeni()
{
    using(SqlConnection pripojeni  = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        pripojeni.Open();

        SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand();
        prikaz.CommandText = " SELECT COUNT (*) FROM HlavniTab";

        int pocet = (int)prikaz.ExecuteScalar();

        pripojeni.Close();
        return pocet;
    }
}
```

This function should connect to the database and count rows in table `HlavniTab`. But I get error on line

```
int pocet = (int)prikaz.ExecuteScalar();
```

It says

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Read the documentation for the constructor of SQLCommand. You need to provide the connection (`pripojeni`) to that constructor so that the SQLCommand knows about the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your sqlcommand was not assigned a connection

try

```
    prikaz.Connection = pripojeni;
```

Comment: Please Mark as answer by click the gray Check below vote up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Connection property in SqlCommand must have to be populated. You can set the connection property using Constructor and also directly set the value to Connection property.

Try -

```
using(SqlConnection pripojeni  = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {

        pripojeni.Open();
        SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand(pripojeni);
        prikaz.CommandText = " SELECT COUNT (*) FROM HlavniTab";
        int pocet = (int)prikaz.ExecuteScalar();
        pripojeni.Close();
        return pocet;

    }
```

or

```
using(SqlConnection pripojeni  = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {

        pripojeni.Open();
        SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand();
        prikaz.Connection = pripojeni;
        prikaz.CommandText = " SELECT COUNT (*) FROM HlavniTab";
        int pocet = (int)prikaz.ExecuteScalar();
        pripojeni.Close();
        return pocet;

    }
```